# How can I get Azure pipeline log file from command line

Tags: command-line, azure-pipelines

I have an Azure pipeline. I can start and see the logs in Chrome. But I would like to do these steps from command line (actually `Cygwin`, but IMHO this is not relevant).

```
az pipelines run --name $pipeline --branch $branch
```

This command gives back a json file format text on the `stdout`. This json has a entry, called `logs`:

```
{
...
  "logs": {
    "id": 0,
    "type": "Container",
    "url": "https://dev.azure.com/myazure/a56234f9-0101-5183-b422-db6f8cb55857/_apis/mybuild/mybuilds/1822266/logs"
  },
...
}
```

If I copy the "url" into `Chrome` I get another `json` format homepage, like:

```
{"count":27,"value":[{"lineCount":371,"createdOn":"2022-10-17T13:38:14.013Z","lastChangedOn":"2022-10-17T13:38:14.183Z","id":1,"type":"Container","url":"https://dev.azure.com/myazure/...
```

But I cannot get back this `json` data from command line. I tried to get by `curl` or `wget`. I got back a HTML page (full with with JavaScript), not the `json` answer.

I also tried `az`:

```
az rest --method get --url "$logs_url"
```

But the response is:

```
Can't derive appropriate Azure AD resource from --url to acquire an access token. If access token is required, use --resource to specify the resource
Not a json response, outputting to stdout. For binary data suggest use "--output-file" to write to a file
```

Then I tried to do:

```
az account get-access-token --query accessToken --output tsv > access_token.tsv
az rest --method get --resource access_token.tsv --url "$logs_url"
```

So, I assume I should get an access token to the URL. But how can I acquire it?

Answer (score 2):

While Rest API referenced by Minxin Yu (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/pipelines/logs/list?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) is the "correct" one I have found that this only gives a listing of the log files associated with this run. I have found the need to filter that result, make an assumption that the longest log is the "Raw Log", and then turn around and make a call to the Builds Log API (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/builds/get-build-log?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) to get the actual log.

The PowerShell Snippet looks something like the below. Using [`az devops invoke`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-devops-cli-extension) and NOT `az rest` as mentioned above, this allows you to reuse the authentication token/mechanism provided by the `az devops` az cli extension. There isn't much documentation on how to properly use it, but [This blog post](http://www.bryancook.net/2021/03/using-azure-cli-to-call-azure-devops.html) got me there.

If anyone has a more direct way to get to this information I would love to use it as opposed to the below. Even better is if az devops could be extended to just support this out of the box.

```bash
$pipelineLogs = az devops invoke --org "https://dev.azure.com/$organization" --area pipelines --resource logs --route-parameters project=$project pipelineId=$pipelineId runId=$runId --api-version=7.0 | ConvertFrom-Json

$longestLogId = ($pipelineLogs.Logs | Sort-Object -Property lineCount -Descending | Select-Object -First 1).id

$buildLog = (az devops invoke --org "https://dev.azure.com/$organization" --area build --resource logs --route-parameters project=$project buildId=$runId logId=$longestLogId --api-version=7.0 --only-show-errors | ConvertFrom-Json).Value
```

I have to use `--only-show-errors` due to https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/14426 as our logs contain various UTF-8 characters, for our purposes we were ok truncating these values, but if you care you might need to evaluate this further.

Answer (score 0):

You can  use curl to call rest api: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/pipelines/logs/list?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0

E.g.

```
curl https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/pipelines/{pipelineId}/runs/{runId}/logs?api-version=6.0-preview.1 ' -H 'Authorization: Basic YourPAT'
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I get back a HTML page. Inside this is stated `<h2>Object moved to <a href="https://spsprodcus3.vssps.visualstudio.com/...`. So I still not have the log json object.. Any idea?

Comment: The PAT needs to be Base64 encoded before you pass it in the Authorization header. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/use-personal-access-tokens-to-authenticate?view=azure-devops&tabs=Windows#use-a-pat-in-your-code

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution:

and my solution inspiring by @aolszowka solution

```
# Retrieve the top log ID

$topLogId = (az devops invoke --area pipelines --resource logs --route-parameters project=$project pipelineId=$pipelineId runId=$runId --api-version=7.0 | ConvertFrom-Json).Logs | Sort-Object -Property lastChangedOn -Descending | Select-Object -First 3 | Sort-Object -Property lineCount -Descending | Select-Object -First 1 | Select-Object -ExpandProperty id

# Output the top log ID for verification
Write-Output $topLogId

# Retrieve the build log using the top log ID
$buildLog = (az devops invoke --org "https://dev.azure.com/$organization" --area build --resource logs --route-parameters project=$project buildId=$runId logId=$topLogId --api-version=7.0 --only-show-errors | ConvertFrom-Json).Value

# Output the build log
Write-Output $buildLog
```

Retrieve the top log ID: This command fetches the top log ID for a specific pipeline run. It does so by querying the Azure DevOps API and sorting the logs by the lastChangedOn property in descending order. It then selects the top 3 logs, further sorts them by lineCount in descending order, and finally selects the top log ID for further processing.

Retrieve the build log: Once the top log ID is obtained, this command uses another Azure CLI command to retrieve the build log. It specifies the project, build ID (run ID), and the previously obtained top log ID to fetch the relevant log file from Azure DevOps.